# Sequence Callout to DS cant parse response

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a problem to parse the callout response of a dss.
I have 2 servers

- WSO2 ESB server (4.9.0)
- WSO2 Application Server (5.3.0) with Data Service (4.3.4) feature installed

i make a payload

```
<payloadFactory description="Payload Processed" media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <p:archivoProcesado xmlns:p="MyDataService">
            <xs:archivo xmlns:xs="MyDataService">$1</xs:archivo>
        </p:archivoProcesado>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('filename')" />
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

After that i make a callout

```
<callout action="archivoProcesado" description="Callout ArchivoProcesado"
    initAxis2ClientOptions="false"
    serviceURL="http://192.168.0.33:9764/services/MyDataService?wsdl">
    <source xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
    <target xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
</callout>
```

To test the result i have:

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$body/*" name="RTA" />
</log>
```

And have:

```
LogMediator RTA = <ArchivosProcesados xmlns="MyDataService"><ArchivoProcesado><procesado>1</procesado></ArchivoProcesado></ArchivosProcesados>
```

but when i want to parse the response i cant

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="//ArchivosProcesados/ArchivoProcesado/procesado/text()"
        name="count" />
</log>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="//ArchivosProcesados" name="xxx" />
</log>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="//ArchivosProcesados/*" name="yyy" />
</log>
```

and the log is blank

```
INFO - LogMediator count = 
INFO - LogMediator xxx = 
INFO - LogMediator yyy =
```

How can i get the value? what am i doing wrong?

MyDSS

```
<query id="archivoProcesado" useConfig="MyDataService">
    <sql>select count(1) as procesado from auto_procesados where archivo = ?</sql>
    <param name="archivo" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <result element="ArchivosProcesados" rowName="ArchivoProcesado">
        <element column="procesado" name="procesado"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="archivoProcesado">
    <call-query href="archivoProcesado">
        <with-param name="archivo" query-param="archivo"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ESB 4.9.0 we have depricated the callout mediator. So could you please use call mediator [1] with [blocking="true"] instead. If it is not working please enable wirelogs as per [2] and check whether you are getting the response from the DSS endpoint properly. A sample call mediator configuration would be as follows.

```
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <address format="soap12" uri="http://192.168.0.33:9764/services/MyDataService"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Also when you get the data from DSS all the data falls under the following name space. http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice. You will have to define a namespace prefix to that namespace and use that in your xpath expressions. An example is given below.

```
<log level="custom">
    <property xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//x:ArchivosProcesados/x:ArchivoProcesado/x:procesado/text()"
        name="count" />
</log>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Call+Mediator

[2] http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: it dosent work for me:
i let you TestDS.xml proxy config [1] and outputlog with wire [2]

[1] [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B44t8SdKZz79c18zSzdSSW4zb2c)
[2] [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B44t8SdKZz79SS13V0pNaFNjR3M)

Comment: I checked your configuration. Your http method is wrong. In the meantime I have made a mistake in the given configuration. Now I have updated it. Could you please try out the above given endpoint configuration now.

Comment: finally i could solve this problem with changing the messageType to json:
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>

and then access through json-eval
<property
                  expression="json-eval($.ArchivosProcesados.ArchivoProcesado.procesado)"
                  name="count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the xmlns attribute to the property mediator.

```
<log level="custom">
    <property xmlns="MyDataService" expression="//ArchivosProcesados/ArchivoProcesado/procesado/text()"
        name="count" />
</log>
```

JP

Comment: the result is a little weird (nothing to log, neither the name nor the equals)

"INFO - LogMediator "

Comment: Try with the namespace that you set at the service. The default is xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", but if you changed it, must use the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i change the callout by a blocking call.

After that i change the messageType to json

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

and then access through json-eval

```
<property expression="json-eval($.ArchivosProcesados.ArchivoProcesado.procesado)"
          name="count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Finally i back the message type to xml:

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
```